# Convolutional Net Model not working on very simple data

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I have generated a very simple dataset. Basically, a 3x3 image with either a column of white pixels or a row of white pixels.

[image: a1ef2d587439b21c2c.th.png] [image: a278cffc11d8908c38.th.png] [image: a35516d69bdf82bab3.th.png] [image: b19abb214427ef5ce1.th.png] [image: b2988962f9bc3ce754.th.png] [image: b36c69bdb057e3258c.th.png]

I am trying to train a convolutional net model to distinguish between the images of either a row white pixels or a column of white pixels. Hoping by the end of the training, the filters(two 2x2 conv filters, no bias in conv-layer) will be doing some sort of vertical/horizontal edge detection.

This is my architecture:

> Conv2d->Relu->Flatten->Dense->Softmax

```py
class MyNet:
    @staticmethod
    def build(width, height, depth, classes):
        # initialize the model along with the input shape to be
        # 'channels last' and the channels dimension itself
        model = Sequential()
        inputShape = (height, width, depth)
        chanDim = -1

        # if we are using "channels first", update the input shape
        # and channels dimension
        if K.image_data_format() == "channels_first":
            inputShape = (depth, height, width)
            chanDim = 1

        # add some layers
        # CONV => RELU
        model.add(Conv2D(filters=2, kernel_size=(2,2), padding="valid",
                          use_bias=False ,input_shape=inputShape))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        # finally, we have a fully connected dense layer  layers and a 
        # softmax classifier:
        model.add(Flatten())
        # softmax classifier
        model.add(Dense(classes))
        model.add(Activation("softmax"))

        # return the constructed network architecture
        return model
```

*I am using a softmax layer as output for this experiment.

I have the following parameters set up:

```py
# initialize the number of epochs to train for, initial learning rate,
# batch size, and image dimensions
np.random.seed(48)
EPOCHS = 100
INIT_LR = 1e-3
BS = 6
IMAGE_DIMS = (3, 3, 1)

model = MyNet.build(3,3,1,2) # create model

# compile model
model.compile(optimizer= keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=INIT_LR),
              loss= tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2,
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# Finally, train model
model.fit(X_train, labels, 
          batch_size=BS,
          epochs=EPOCHS,
          verbose=1
         )
```

Pretty straight forward classification task, but for some reason, which escapes me, this model doesn't learn squat!

```
...
Epoch 96/100
6/6 [==============================] - 0s 10ms/step - loss: 0.8133 - acc: 0.5000
Epoch 97/100
6/6 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: 0.8133 - acc: 0.5000
Epoch 98/100
6/6 [==============================] - 0s 4ms/step - loss: 0.8133 - acc: 0.5000
Epoch 99/100
6/6 [==============================] - 0s 4ms/step - loss: 0.8133 - acc: 0.5000
Epoch 100/100
6/6 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: 0.8133 - acc: 0.5000
```

I have tried changing the learning rate, number of epochs, the optimizer, loss function, etc. but still nothing.

With the random seed set to 48, I get the following 2 filters which remain same after training :(, so no learning at all.

```py
model.get_weights()[0][:,:,0,0]

> array([[ 0.23327285, -0.06844258],
>       [ 0.61764306, -0.46921107]], dtype=float32)

--------------------------------------
model.get_weights()[0][:,:,0,1]
> array([[ 0.68603402,  0.13425004],
>       [ 0.39129239,  0.23840684]], dtype=float32)
```

BTW, I ran this experiment on a conv-net I created from scratch(all numpy) with the same architecture, it performed much better.

The data is set up as follows:

```py
image_a  = np.array([
    [0, 0, 0],
    [255, 255, 255],
    [0, 0, 0],
], dtype="uint8")

image_a_2  = np.array([
    [255, 255, 255],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
], dtype="uint8")

image_a_3  = np.array([
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [255, 255, 255],
], dtype="uint8")

image_b  = np.array([
    [0, 255, 0],
    [0, 255, 0],
    [0, 255, 0],
], dtype="uint8")

image_b_2  = np.array([
    [255, 0, 0],
    [255, 0, 0],
    [255, 0, 0],
], dtype="uint8")

image_b_3  = np.array([
    [0, 0,  255],
    [0, 0,  255],
    [0, 0,  255],
], dtype="uint8")

X_train = np.array([image_a,image_a_2, image_a_3, image_b, image_b_2, image_b_3])

# set up in correct shape for tensorflow (batch, height, width, channel)
X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 3, 3, 1)

y = [0,0,0,1,1,1] # images with row of white pixels->0, and col of white->1
labels = np.eye(2, )[y]
```

So, someone where am I going wrong.

Comment: I would try: kernel_size(1,1). more filters. padding="same".

Comment: **BTW, I ran this experiment on a conv-net I created from scratch(all numpy) for an experiment that did much better, creating more confusion.** I dont understand this sentance

Comment: @akhetos I created a conv-net with the same architecture as the one in TensorFlow, but from scratch using numpy, only. That experiment showed that the network was learning. So, not even a semblance of learning in TensorFlow is a bit confusing.

Comment: updated the confusing statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2` loss function which expect logit inputs, see [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2) (unscaled logits, as it does the softmax in the loss calculation for optimization), hence you should not have a `softmax` activation at the output of your `MyNet`. If you dont want to remove the softmax activation on the output of `MyNet` because of inference, you can use the `tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy` loss function, with `from_logits=False` instead.

---

**EDIT:**

Another problem is that your Conv2D layer only uses 2 filters. Hence only two sets of weights to learn the 6 types of situations. This seems to be a problem, as when this is changed to 6 (together with `padding='same') the model gives 100% accuracy.

I also changed the optimizer to adam, as my experience with this optimizer is better. And I scaled the data between 0 and 1.
see below code for a working example.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
import numpy as np
class MyNet:
    @staticmethod
    def build(width, height, depth, classes):
        # initialize the model along with the input shape to be
        # 'channels last' and the channels dimension itself
        model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
        inputShape = (height, width, depth)

        # if we are using "channels first", update the input shape
        # and channels dimension
        if K.image_data_format() == "channels_first":
            inputShape = (depth, height, width)
        # add some layers
        # CONV => RELU
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=6, kernel_size=(2,2), padding="same",
                          use_bias=False ,input_shape=inputShape))
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation("relu"))
        # finally, we have a fully connected dense layer  layers and a 
        # softmax classifier:
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
        # softmax classifier
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(classes))
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation("softmax"))

        # return the constructed network architecture
        return model

image_a  = np.array([
    [0, 0, 0],
    [255, 255, 255],
    [0, 0, 0],
], dtype="uint8")

image_a_2  = np.array([
    [255, 255, 255],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
], dtype="uint8")

image_a_3  = np.array([
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [255, 255, 255],
], dtype="uint8")

image_b  = np.array([
    [0, 255, 0],
    [0, 255, 0],
    [0, 255, 0],
], dtype="uint8")

image_b_2  = np.array([
    [255, 0, 0],
    [255, 0, 0],
    [255, 0, 0],
], dtype="uint8")

image_b_3  = np.array([
    [0, 0,  255],
    [0, 0,  255],
    [0, 0,  255],
], dtype="uint8")
X_train = np.array([image_a,image_a_2, image_a_3, image_b, image_b_2, image_b_3])

# set up in correct shape for tensorflow (batch, height, width, channel)
X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 3, 3, 1)/255

y = [0,0,0,1,1,1] # images with row of white pixels->0, and col of white->1
labels = np.eye(2, )[y]



# initialize the number of epochs to train for, initial learning rate,
# batch size, and image dimensions
tf.set_random_seed(48)
EPOCHS = 100
BS = 6
IMAGE_DIMS = (3, 3, 1)

model = MyNet.build(3,3,1,2) # create model

# compile model
model.compile(optimizer= tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
              loss= tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# Finally, train model
model.fit(X_train, labels, 
          batch_size=BS,
          epochs=EPOCHS,
          verbose=1
         )
pred = model.predict(X_train)
pred_labels = (pred>0.5)
print('All predictions equal to labels, ' + str(np.all(pred_labels ==labels)))
```

which results in the output

```
> All predictions equal to labels, True
```

Comment: using `tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy` weirdly gives me error that
"logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [6,2] and labels shape [12]"

but labels are alread in shape (6,2)

Comment: @RafayKhan, yeah you are right, didn't have time to test it should have been `tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy` instead of `tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy`.
See updated answer with code above for a fully working example where prediction=labels.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This seems to do the job. This entire endeavor was to create an edge filter like "Robert's" 2x2 edge filter. With your code, I can come close to it. BTW I did change the code back to 2 filters and after around 5k epochs the answer came close to what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

you should normalize the data into the range [0, 1]. If you have the range [0, 255] it is likely that the network wont learn.
Just divide the dataset by 255.
Furthermore, i would use the adam optimizer and binary crossentropy as loss.

Comment: Yeah, normalizing should help "improve" the result, but there is no learning happening to improve the result. Secondly, I am trying to create filters to be used on normal images without me going in and augmenting the data.

Comment: Did you try it? I had it on many occasions that the NN does nothing when the data is not normalized.